# compass sprites not showing in browser

Tags: sass, compass-sass, sprite, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation 3 built on Sass, i have managed to import the sprites and the images folder displaying all generated sprites but none of them showing up in browser.

HTML

```
<div class="six columns">
    <a href="#"><h2>Al Umrah</h2></a>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
$siteImages-layout:smart;
@import "siteImages/*.png";
@include all-siteImages-sprites;


h2{@include siteImages-sprite(al-umrah-logo);height:261px;}
```

GENERATED CSS

```
.siteImg-sprite, .siteImg-al-umrah-logo, .siteImg-hajj, .siteImg-home, .siteImg-umrah,     h2 {
background:url('/images/siteImg-sf72f1f5d54.png') no-repeat
}
.siteImg-al-umrah-logo {
background-position:0 -384px
}
.siteImg-hajj {
background-position:0 -128px
}
.siteImg-home {
background-position:0 -256px
}
.siteImg-umrah {
background-position:0 0
}
h2 {
background-position:0 -384px;
height:261px
}
```

RB CONFIG

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

# relative_assets = true
```

PS: i have this folder on desktop

Comment: Did the sprite get generated?  Your h2 doesn't have a width, it isn't collapsing down to a 0 width element, is it?

Comment: I am using Zurb's Foundation css framework hence i don't think that i need to set the width as that is created by the framework. I have given the height which is fine, Yes sprite get generated.

Comment: What does the generated CSS look like?

Comment: I edited my question with Generated CSS.

Comment: You're viewing the HTML document from a Windows machine?  The path to your image doesn't exist:  /images/siteImg-sf72f1f5d54.png.  Try enabling `relative_assets`.

Comment: Yes i am on windows machine and enabling relative_assets did work! thank you so much. I tried this earlier but for some reason it was not working but for now it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The CSS document is requesting a file that doesn't exist on your test machine.  Since you're viewing the document from your desktop, the absolute path to your image might look something like `C:\Users\username\desktop\path\to\images\siteImg-sf72f1f5d54.png`, not `/images/siteImg-sf72f1f5d54.png`.

Enabling `relative_assets` should change the path to something like `../images/siteImg-sf72f1f5d54.png`, which would work for both your test machine and your production server.